# Describing a Subgroup Generated by a Given Set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm very confused as of right now in my abstract algebra course. I would much rather do some real analysis but that's the the point. Anyways, I need to describe a subgroup generated by a set and list the elements if possible.

$$\langle 32,24\rangle \in \mathbb{Z}$$

I would not like the answer to the question as of yet, but a hint on how to approach this would be appreciated. I know it is not very complicated. But I can't seem to find this in our book, and this has been hand assigned by our professor. A general case would be appreciated. I want to say that we use $\gcd{(32,24)}=8$ but I do not know where to go from there. I'd like this fact but I do not particularly know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's as much of a hint as I think can be given without giving the answer directly:

Is it possible for any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ to be non-cyclic? Cyclic groups are completely characterized by their order and generating element.

Comment: No, I do not believe so. Every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ has a generator and thus making it cyclic. So basically, we have the cyclic group generated by 32 and 24. We take the greatest common divisor and get 8. Now, 8 is the generator for this cyclic group because for any $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, 8 will be a generator for $32m$ and $24n$. Now my question is, where does the gcd being the generator come from? What allows this to happen. I'm thinking, because the greatest common divisor is 8, 8 will divide any form of 32 and 24, so $32\times n$ or $32^n$ will always be generated by 8. The same for 24.

Comment: I think your language "will be a generator for $32m$ and $32n$ is a little confused, but it looks like you've basically found the answer to your original question, which is that your subgroup is the cyclic subgroup generated by 8.

The proof could proceed by showing that if $x$ is not in $\langle 8 \rangle$ then $x$ is not in your subgroup. The elements of $\langle 8 \rangle$ are exactly the multiples of 8. Use the property of greatest common divisor to show that everything in $\langle 32, 24\rangle$ is a multiple of 8.

Comment: @Frumpy : The key observation you need is that every element of your subgroup is by definition of the form $32m + 24n$, and that all numbers of this form are multiples of 8.

Comment: I do not have to prove this for this specific homework, but would a proof such as showing that because the gcd is 8, then 8 divides any form of 32 and 24, thus 8 is the cyclic subgroup generator of the cyclic group made of 32 and 24?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "any form of 32 and 24". First prove that 8 is inside your subgroup by showing that it is equal to $32m+24n$ where $m, n$ are any integers. This prove that the subgroup generated by 32 and 24 contains the subgroup generated by 8.

Next prove that every number of the form $32m+24n$ can be written as $8k$. This proves the containment in the other direction, and you have shown equality.

Note that by definition $\langle 32, 24 \rangle$ is the set of integers of the form $32m + 24n$.

Comment: I was a bit confused because without being told otherwise, we don't know if our operation is multiplication or addition? For example either $32^n$ or $32n$? What I mean by any form is that, because 8 divides both 32 and 24, it follows that 8 divides $32n+32m$.

Comment: That's exactly correct. We (at least I) assume that by $\mathbb{Z}$ the question implicitly means $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. $(\mathbb{Z}, \cdot)$ is not a group! (You should verify why it's not a group using the group axioms)

Comment: Ahh, how stupid of me. Inverse axion fails for the requirement of being a group. I have a follow up question if you do not mind. If we are working with $\langle4,14\rangle\in\mathbb{z}_{18}$ and we know that the $\gcd=2$. Is this enough to say the subgroup generated is $\langle2\rangle$? Due to working with all even numbers, as well as reducing with an even number, we will always result in an even number, meaning that 2 will always be a generator? But I think there is a problem because $14+_{18}4=0$ and this might cause a problem.

Comment: The argument in your last sentence says that all numbers in the group will be even, but this is not the same as saying that all even numbers will be in the group.

But we don't even need this argument here because 2 is a multiple of 4 modulo 18 ;)

EDIT: The "problem" you identify is not a problem. The groups generated by 2 and 4 modulo 18 are identical.

Comment: All even numbers will not be in the group. So does this imply that our subgroup (asked to be listed if possible) is generated by 2 and includes 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16, and I guess the trivial case 0?

Comment: Those are all the even "numbers" in $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$. Be careful when writing your homework answers to be precise, especially when you aren't comfortable with the material. Tips:

1. Every time you claim that two groups are equal, you should prove that they contain each other. This will help ensure you aren't leaving something out.

2. Don't abuse notation unless you and your audience are both comfortable with it. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ aren't numbers but equivalence classes. $gcd$ isn't defined there because there's no concept of "greatest".

Comment: I appreciate your consistent replies and help. If we are working in $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$, isn't it assumed that $\mathbb{z}_{18}=\{0,1,2,\ldots,17\}$? And we will never have the case where $4n+14m=(2k+1)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. You're right, I am not comfortable with the material as of yet, but I am trying to learn.

Comment: Yes, but more concretely they are equivalence classes of numbers $[0], \ldots , [17]$ where two numbers are defined as equivalent if they have the same remainder when divided by 18. Writing simply the numbers is fine, but you must be careful not to believe that these "numbers" operate in the same way that their counterparts in $\mathbb{Z}$ operate. For example, $16 + 4 = 18 +2$, so $16 + 4 = 2$ modulo $18$. You can easily see why it makes little sense to ask which divisor of an element in $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ is "greatest".

Comment: I will have to work on that. I truly dislike abstract algebra. I would much rather stick to number theory and real analysis (I'm an undergraduate at the moment). Thank you very much for your help tonight :)